# Angular js, not showing socket data at Table (ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sockets

```
 div(ng-controller="dashController")
    nav.navbar.navbar-expand-sm.navbar-dark.fixed-top
      .container
        img(src='../images/Dashboard.png', alt='logo', width='180px')
        ul.navbar-nav
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link.active(href='#')
              i.fas.fa-sign-out-alt  Çıkış Yap   

 main
      .container
        .row
          .col-md-1
          .col-md-7
            .card
              .card-header
                h5 Ozkaynak Hesaplaması
              #oTab.card-body
                .table-responsive
                  table.table.table-stripped.table-hover(cellspacing='0')
                    thead.thead.bg-primary.text-white
                      tr
                        th.th-sm Musteri No
                        th.th-sm Ozkaynak
                    tbody
                     tr(ng-repeat="equs in equss track by $index")
                        td {{equs.mNo}}
                        td {{equs.ozkynk}}
```

this is my pug.file

```
app.controller('dashController', ['$scope',($scope) =>{
   const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('ozkaynak',(data)=>{
            $scope.equss = data;
             $scope.$apply(); 
            console.log($scope.equss);
     })
```

this is my Controller.file

Hello. I'm try to show my data at table but I couldn't. I'm success when I write console.log(scope.equss) but data not showing on window. How can I fix this.

This is my data in the console:

[image]

Comment: i did not try in timeout. it could be true. I will try it.

Comment: Can you post the value of `console.log($scope.equss)` ?

Comment: 0: {mNo: 12, ozkynk: 1.8340553051309822}
1: {mNo: 200, ozkynk: 1.2171679175254009}
2: {mNo: 404, ozkynk: 1.000259591203633}
3: {mNo: 406, ozkynk: 1}
4: {mNo: 407, ozkynk: 0.8792038558162468}
5: {mNo: 607, ozkynk: 1.3248722280551353}
6: {mNo: 777, ozkynk: 1.0575929081504263}
7: {mNo: 862, ozkynk: 1.2677970046267748}
8: {mNo: 1061, ozkynk: 6.805391200712722}
...

Comment: That's my Object Array from socket.emit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `$scope.equss = data.equs` since your `data` is an object  `{ equs: Array(21) }`

Comment: @safaaytan Its a common mistake, make sure to check response closely when working with requests